Positive invariance of solution using tangency of vector field
I am reading the book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-72122-4, they have considered the system of differential equation $\dot{x}=f(x,t)$. They have proved the positive invariance of the solution for any $t$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}_+$, i.e., $x_i(t)\geq 0$ for any $i$ using the fact "vector field $f(x)$ is tangent to the coordinate or pointing to the interior of $\mathbb{R}^{n}_+$". Can anyone explain what does this mean? How tangency of vector field implies invariance?

You can check the keywords: forward invariance, Nagumo's Theorem of invariance or Bony–Brezis theorem, viability theory, etc
